# What are uses of UIGuidedAccessRestrictionDelegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am not sure about UIGuidedAccessRestrictionDelegate where these delegates can be used? As this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGuidedAccessRestrictionsDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is not so clear how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says:

> Adopting the UIGuidedAccessRestrictionDelegate protocol in your
>   **application delegate** allows you to add custom restrictions for the Guided Access feature in iOS.

Meaning you need to adopt this protocol in your **application's delegate class** (the class that conforms to **UIApplicationDelegate**).

There's a [sample online](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2216/Listings/CustomContentAccessibility_APLAppDelegate_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014019-CustomContentAccessibility_APLAppDelegate_h-DontLinkElementID_3) if you need some examples.

Comment: Thx for sample link. One Quick question what all Restriction can made. Can I use it for Incoming Call restriction.